# DataView component in SPD attaches needless strings to field values

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, sharepoint-designer, dataview

In SharePoint Designer I use some lists as sources and then link them together with an operation GetListItems (I fetch items from multiple lists on different site collections for rollup/aggregation):
[alt text http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/1807/ss20090428101310.png](http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/1807/ss20090428101310.png)

Now something is fine as I managed to get the result: [alt text http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/4835/ss20090428101013.png](http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/4835/ss20090428101013.png)

But the strings that are attached to field result (6;#, 2;#) is... disturbing.
How can I get rid from those attached strings? They are not attached to all fields, but to some (important ones):

[alt text http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/1647/ss20090428100732.png](http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/1647/ss20090428100732.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, well usally that happens - you keep searching for answer, then seek for help and find it yourself.

I used substring xsl function, to strip away those first characters. Messy, if i want to add links to that table, but works.

[alt text http://img2.imageshack.us/img2/3117/ss20090428102714.png](http://img2.imageshack.us/img2/3117/ss20090428102714.png)

By the way, the main question how to rollup content from multiple site collections has been journey to me for several days already. If anyone is in the same situation, I recommend (well because I found myself an answer there) these:

- [How-To Rollup two lists in two site
  collections on a page](http://blogs.technet.com/harikumh/archive/2009/02/19/how-to-rollup-two-lists-in-two-site-collections-on-a-page.aspx)
- Or a better way to use for a single
  site collection: [SharePoint
  Customisation Tricks: Use The
  SPDataSource, Luke!](http://blog.mattsmith.co.nz/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=c7bdac80-1d4e-4732-9e67-cefde9c03d31&ID=56) (Good links
  inside that article).
- Something I didn't touch, because I
  didn't need such an advanced method,
  but maybe someone does: [Populating
  data sources in code](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/populating-data-sources-in-code)